# Handling Authentication for users in Sitecore 5.3.1

Tags: .net, authentication, sitecore

In Sitecore 6+ I can use the following code to check wheter a user has been logged in:

```
   string logonUser = base.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];

   // check of de gebuiker geautenticeerd is (bijv. door in een andere browser venster in het beheer in te loggen.)
   if (Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      Response.Redirect("/", true);
   }
```

In Sitecore 5.3.1. on which one of our customers is running I want to implement similar functionality. I want to determine wheter a user has entered valid credentials and then log that user to the system. After that I want to be able to determine if this user is logged in by checking the Session vars on each return to the website. I can't find the method to use to do this.
Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encourage you to browse `Sitecore.SecurityModel` namespace, especially `Domain` class. It contains the methods you'd probably find useful (`IsLoggedIn`, `Login`, `Logout`). You can download the help file of Sitecore API from [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Resources/Documentation/Sitecore%20V5.3.1%20API.aspx).

Also, Sitecore security model is based on ASP.NET security **starting from version 6**. In 5.x a user is still an item in the appropriate database. Hope this info can help you.

Comment: Thanks again Yan. I already had the solution but your answer comes closest to how I found it :).

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

```
if (Sitecore.Context.IsLoggedIn) {

} else {
  Response.Redirect("http://" + Request.Url.Host + "/sitecore/login");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. I think as long as a user can be found in the current context, you can assume the user is logged ind.

so

```
Sitecore.Context.User != null
```

is probably enough.